# Can I mount and run an iso from my terminal?

Tags: installation, gnome-terminal, iso

I broke my gui, and am trying to install an iso of windows I have. Is it possible to do from the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You must login as a root user, if not root user then switch to root user using following command:

```
$ su -
```

2) Create the directory i.e. mount point:

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/disk
```

3) Use mount command as follows to mount iso file called disk1.iso:

```
# mount -o loop disk1.iso /mnt/disk
```

4) Change directory to list files stored inside an ISO image:

```
# cd /mnt/disk
# ls -l
```

Then you can run whatever you want from your ISO

Comment: Thank you! I'm having a problem locating the iso as the root user. It says it cannot find the directory. Do I need to input the path or just the iso file?

Comment: drag and drop the iso file in the terminal

Comment: Can't I have no gui, which is why i'm trying to do it through the terminal.

Comment: ok what is your user name and where is the iso located?

Comment: User- julie. Iso located at julie/Downloads/iso. But I cant find the path there from the root user.

Comment: cd /home/julie/Downloads

Comment: This is a correct answer to mount an ISO in the terminal... but you do realize he won't be able to install windows this way? The iso should be burned in a cd and boot the machine with it.